# "when V-ing" Is it a participle?

Tags: participle-phrases

Two people gave me an advice to put "when" in a sentence like this:

> There are some points to consider (think about) when having a pet.

At first, I didn't put "when" between "consider (think about)" and "having."

I know I can put V-ing phrase as a participle after a complete sentence.  Is the "when" put to make it clear that the participle concerns time?

Could you please tell me what this is?

Comment: By 'having a pet', do you mean getting one? I would say _when_ or _before buying/getting a pet_. You need to think about the practicalities _at the time that_ you buy your pet.

Comment: @KateBunting Oh, thank you so much!!  I wanted to mean like "There are some things you should remember or think about (for example, your responsibility) if you are planning to get a pet, or you have a pet."  It's so difficult to express things well...!